Why do airplane air conditioning systems use a turbine to expand air?
Why do airplane air conditioning systems use a turbine to expand air? The cooling medium in airplanes is air. The Joule-Thomson effect causes the temperature to drop during expansion under these conditions. So why doesn't the air conditioning system rely on this effect as car air conditioning systems do with the R-134 refrigerant? Is the pressure used in these systems too low for the temperature drop to be significant? Expansion in the turbine is a process close to isentropic, and the additional work obtained during such expansion is necessary to lower the temperature?

So calculate the change in temperature - you seem to know the theory...

Planes are moving a lot faster than cars.

https://www.pilotmall.com/blogs/news/aircraft-air-conditioning-all-the-details-you-need-to-know?srsltid=AfmBOor7EXeoNXOCc9BqPk4zauaaF18X3h-IrXEP11vxC7M5DTuGBQgg

" The work extracted by the expansion turbine is transmitted by a shaft to spin the pack's centrifugal compressor and an inlet fan which draws in the external air for the heat exchangers during ground running; ram air is used in flight. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_cycle_machine

A classic refrigerant heatpump is heavy and contains hazardous (toxic and combustible) materials and a lot can go wrong with them. Especially if you need it to have enough capacity to handle a minimally insulated big metal tube. In a lot of territories you need to be certified to service them and need to have specialized equipment to capture the refrigerant. Then you need to consider the logistics of a refrigerant changeover, you will end up with a fleet with a mixed set of refrigerants.
An aircraft's pack on the other hand is almost purely mechanical and very simple. There's only a few moving parts and you don't need to be specially certified to repair any part on them. If there is a leak you don't immediately lose air conditioning.
